# Differences between connectors Mule ESB and WSO2 ESB

Tags: soap, service, mule, esb, wso2-esb

Using Mule ESB I noticed that you can connect (via anypoint connectors) applications, databases, web services etc.
Since I am making a comparison between different ESB (Enterprise Service Bus) I ran into WSO2 ESB and reading the documentation it seems that allows to interact only web services (through SOAP communications).
Someone confirms what I wrote? Or WSO2 ESB is flexible as Mule ESB and I'm wrong (if so what are the differences)?

Answer (score 3):

WSO2 ESB also has the concept of connectors which you can use to connect to external applications, databases, file systems and web services hosted in cloud or in internal networks. Here is a webinar which you can follow to get more information.
http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2014/09/esb-connectors-for-on-premise-and-cloud-integration-solutions/

Answer (score 2):

I can't help as my knowledge of WSO2 is limited. What I could do is to recommend you the book [open source ESB in action](http://www.manning.com/rademakers/), although outdated its data, the introduction is amazing and the comparison methodology is also good. You could follow the same approach with the state of the art today.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the connectivity to applications, databases, different protocols are already available with wso2 ESB and wso2 product stack out of the box. However there are some connectors that will support integration with on-premises legacy systems and additional protocols. eg: ejb, is08583, kafka, etc.